# Cron generated by Whenever doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

It seems that my cron task doesn't work.
Here is the result of "contrab -l"

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/mtaville/mtaville_staging/releases/20140827132856/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/mtaville/mtaville_staging/releases/20140827132856 && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake events:archive_outdated_event --silent'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/mtaville/mtaville_staging/releases/20140827132856/config/schedule.rb
```

Here is some lines of logfile :

```
Aug 28 13:42:01 67872hd63015 CRON[489]: (mtaville) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/mtaville/mtaville_staging/releases/20140827132856 && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake events:archive_outdated_event --silent')
Aug 28 13:42:18 67872hd63015 crontab[495]: (mtaville) LIST (mtaville)
Aug 28 13:43:01 67872hd63015 CRON[498]: (mtaville) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/mtaville/mtaville_staging/releases/20140827132856 && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake events:archive_outdated_event --silent')
```

When I copy/past the code of log :

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/mtaville/mtaville_staging/releases/20140827132856 && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake events:archive_outdated_event --silent'
```

it works !

What's the problem ?

The cron file is generated by Whenever a Gem of Ruby on Rails.

**EDIT**
I had this to my crontab

```
* * * * * cd && touch .it_works
```

And... it works...

Comment: Is your RAILS_ENV correct ? Staging seem a bit weird

Comment: yes, staging is a test environment where I deploy my features first !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for those who have the problem :

**Create a job type :**

```
job_type :rbenv_rake, %Q{export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" ; eval "$(rbenv init -)" ; cd :path && :environment_variable=:environment bundle exec rake :task --silent :output }
```

**Use it :**

```
rbenv_rake "cars:import"
```

Answer (score 0):

You told linux what to do as a part of cronjob. But you haven't started cronjob yet. To start cronjob /etc/init.d/crond start.

Comment: Cron is started. There is log !